# Apache does not load/work - even with htaccess authentication

Tags: authentication, httpd, apache-2.2

I've set up my VPS, installed httpd under `yum install httpd` and restarted the server. When I've added a `.htaccess` to `/var/www/html` nothing works at all, which inside the htaccess file has an authentication required and does not show anything except gives me an access to the "protected" directory.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The `.htpasswd` exists, but still nothing works at all. I've also tried a simple rewrite rule and that doesn't even work.

How do you get apache to work (or run properly)? Everything is just running and working fine except apache.

My server is running `Centos 5 x86_64 Standard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow overrides for htaccess to work.

See this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html  Look at "AllowOverride"

Comment: Alright. But that isn't helping, do I have to edit the `httpd.conf` or put it in a `.htaccess` file on the root of `/var/www/html`?

Comment: In httpd.conf find "<Directory "/var/www/html">"   Below that, look for "AllowOverride None" - now check out the docs I linked and change "None" to your preference. And reload apache for the changes to be applied.